# Raspberry Pi share ppp0 via USB

Tags: pi-3, networking, sensor, modem

I have the following setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Sixfab 3G/4G Base Shield v2
- Queltec UC20

I have connection to the internet over ppp0 interface but now I want to connect the Instantel Micromate sensor to Raspberry Pi via USB and share that ppp0 to sensor. What I actually want to do is for Raspberry Pi to actually act as a modem (meaning that all traffic from USB will be directly rerouted to ppp0). The problem is that this sensor also recognizes regular USBs and thus Raspberry Pi needs to present itself as a   modem. I tried connecting the sensor to Raspberry Pi via USB without SD card in Raspberry Pi and nothing happened of course, apart from RPi turning on and shield lights blinking. However, when I insert SD card into Raspberry and connected the sensor again, it broke the sensor because the sensor thought it needs to install firmware from there or something.

I was Googling a lot on how to make Raspberry Pi a USB modem, but failed to find anything useful. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use an ethernet connection over USB from the sensor, means using OTG USB Gadget mode? What do you mean with "*this sensor also recognizes regular USBs*"? Are there any differences?

Comment: I have 3G internet on Raspberry Pi that I want to share with the sensor, however Raspberry Pi must work completely as a modem because the sensor also recognises "regular USBs" (by which I mean MassStorage for example). The problem is, that if Raspberry Pi does not introduce itself as a modem, the sensor will only be able to copy files to/from RPi as it would only be an USB stick. I hope this is clear

Comment: No, not completely clear. You wrote "*connect the Instantel Micromate sensor to Raspberry Pi via USB and share that ppp0 to sensor*". **ppp0** is the (virtual) ethernet interface of the 3G connection. Sharing this with the sensor, its connection must also have an ethernet interface, maybe **usb0**. Does the sensor have an ethernet interface on the RasPi?

Answer (score 2):

The raspberry pi would have to act as a serial device server/client in order to communicate with the Micromate through its USB serial connection.  You'll need to use a Sabrent FTDI compatible serial cable and set the modem type to "generic" instead of USB to PC on the Micromate.  If you're looking for advice on low cost modems or settings for your Pi that work with the Micromate, reach out to [DRW Associates](https://drwalter.com/contact-us) (they are a US based Instantel dealer) Their people are awesome at making custom systems.  If you're looking for a portable server, it would have to run Blastware, they can help you with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> 1. Connecting the MicroMate sensor to Raspberry Pi via USB without SD card in Raspberry Pi and nothing happened of course, apart from RPi
>      turning on and shield lights blinking.
> 2. However, when insertin SD card into Raspberry and connected the sensor again, it broke the sensor because the sensor thought it needs
>      to install firmware from there or something.

***Answer***

I skimmed the documents and know that the MicroMate sensor is a smart guy who can work alone as a master without a computer, eg Rpi, logging data into USB flash etc.  And when connected to a Rpi, it can talk with Rpi and upgrade its firmware.

The problem is if we don't know the sensor's language, such as the simple AT commands set like:

> request = "AT?", response = "OK",
>
> request = "UPGRADE FIRMWARE?", response = "YES, NOW READY TO TRANSFER,
>   ...".

In other words, without the user guide, there is nothing we can do. :(

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you meant commands for Micromate? There are none, I already spoke to Instantel. However, connecting Micromate to a modem allows Micromate to transfer data to a remote PC, but instead of modem I want to use the setup in the question. Is that possible, so can Raspberry Pi work as a modem (meaning turning it into a slave of some kind)?

Comment: I see.  If MicroMate has no command set, then it might be a very dumb device - if there is no input from computer, then it just blindly sends output to USB flash (if manually selected by touch screen).  And when there is input from computer, it blindly accepts input data as firmware to update, ... I know my brainstorming wild guesses sound silly, but that is what I can do with limited info, ..  About turning Rpi into a slave/modem, I know too little about 3G/4G shield to suggest anything.  Sorry about that.